# Automatically extract image from acsm pdf file open with Adobe Digital Edition

Tags: ubuntu, printing

I bought a pdf book that is protected (.acsm) and can only be opened with Adobe Digital Edition. As I am old school and that I like feeling the papersheet :D, I would like to print physically some of its pages to write annotations (not with okular).

I am with Ubuntu 22.04, so first I had to use Wine to install and open ADE. And from there, impossible to print this document from ADE (I guess it is because it is protected).

So I thought to printscreen the interesting pages and print them as images. However the interesting chapter is 40 pages long.

I remember there was a way to automatically repeat the action I am doing with my keyboard (i.e. printscreen, next page, printscreen, next page...). But I cannot find this anymore. Some ideas ?

Or any other solutions?

Thanks in advance